# Screen lock notification

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications

I have a [Gionee P4](http://www.gsmarena.com/gionee_pioneer_p4-6711.php) device, updated to Kitkat.

I try to all apps notification comes out at my device is screen off ya locked.
I have tried all software for solve this problem.

First I've tried [NiLS Lock Screen Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget). In this app it says *NiLS notification started* in your device setting, but I try in device setting as *NiLS Notification* are enable always.

This type enable not for this app but as app I have installed in my device so notifications are enabled. But the problem is that as I use any software for screen lock notification as app notification are disabled all time.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Your question is really hard to understand (a language barrier I guess). I've tried to improve it a little, but am not sure if I understood correctly: "I try to all apps notification comes out at my device is screen off ya locked" – do you mean you want all notifications shown while your screen is off and locked (lockscreen notifications – your mentioning of *NiLS* suggests as much), and the screen (optionally) switching on shortly (without unlocking) whenever a notification appears?

Answer (score 0):

In settings there are settings for Notifications Bar Icon settings there you can turn off notifications for targeted apps. But the only problem with this approach is that you won't see the notifications even after Unlocking the phone. But hey if you want some privacy then it's worth it and it doesn't even require an app.